# How do I check if a div has a specific child div inside of it in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div class="main"></div>` and sometimes there is a `<div class="second" ></div>` inside of it. If the `.second` div is not there then I do not want to show the `.main` div.

I have tried this with no success

```
if ($(".main").find(".second").length > 0){ 
  $("main").hide();
}
```

Comment: What you have written should work properly.

Comment: $(".main").hide();. Notice the missing period

Comment: it should `if ($(".main").find(".second").length == 0)` because you want to `main` div hide if second div does not exist

Comment: @Nico only if the typo in `$("main")` is fixed.

Comment: `$('main')` is a perfectly valid selector and could be intentional, though I have to agree it is probably a typo here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query selector is correct but `if` condition is wrong

```
if ($(".main").find(".second").length > 0) {
   $("main").hide();
}
```

should be

```
if ($(".main").find(".second").length == 0) {
   $(".main").hide();
}
```

because you want to `main` div hide if `second` div does not exist

Comment: Why do you have `.length .length` in your first code block?

Comment: Sorry, copy paste issue. Updated. Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($(".main").children(".second").length > 0){ 
    $(".main").hide();
}
```